# Javascript (jQuery) - Problem with $.post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

So, for some reason my script refuses to work, although it seems to be correct.

I tried using $.ajax instead, but not working with that either. Any ideas what's gone wrong?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#saveForm .submit').click(function() {
      var _user = $('#saveForm .user');
       _userId = $('#saveForm .userId');
       _password = $('#saveForm .password');

      $('#saveForm').append('<p>Loading...</p>');

      $.post("ajax/fetchPhotos.php", {user:_user, userId:_userId, password:_password}, function(data) {
       alert(data);
      });

      return false;
     });
});
</script>
```

In ajax/fetchPhotos.php i have this:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
session_start();
require_once("includes/functions.php");
require_once("includes/pclzip.lib.php");

/*
Huge block of code here (commented out for the moment)
*/
echo "wut?";
```

So, when clicking .submit, it should send a request to fetchPhotos.php with three params and then alert "wut?". Right now the page hangs in chrome.. nothing happens. In firefox the page just refreshes. I do get one error in the console, but i only see it for a split second as the page refreshes directly.

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: What does your markup look like?

Comment: In Firefox, have you looked at the `Error Console`?  This is inside the `Tools` menu.  Information inside the `Error Console` does not vanish unless you clear it manually.  Also, if you look at the logs for the web-server where the PHP script is hosted, do you see any requests made to your script?  Also, the `HttpFox` extension on Firefox will help you track requests and responses.

Comment: @Nick, i don't see why you would need the markup. It's simple though, i have a form with three inputs whith classes. @Ayaz, i didn't know about that! Thanks. This is what i see in the error console: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/Q0Y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must use the .val() method to get the value of the inputs.

try this way:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#saveForm .submit').bind('click', function() {
        var 
            user = $('#saveForm .user').val(),
            id = $('#saveForm .userId').val(),
            password = $('#saveForm .password').val();

        $('#saveForm').append('<p>Loading...</p>');

        $.post("ajax/fetchPhotos.php", {user:user, userId:id, password:password}, function(data) { 
            alert(data);
        });

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems syntax related problem and also try with absolute url or can do in this way

```
new Ajax.Request("ajax/fetchPhotos.php", {
            method: 'post',
            parameters: 'id='+id,
            onComplete: function(transport) {
            alert(transport.responseText);
            }
            });
```